# How can I access to the monitor image data?

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, screenshot

#### 1. The problem I've encountered

Hi, I'm currently making a desktop application with Electron.js. Meanwhile, I have needed a feature of taking a screenshot (including the mouse cursor) but this is a problem for me because I do not know how to do this.

I think the reason for me not to be able to solve this problem is that I have no knowledge about operating systems. I think the meaning of "taking a screenshot" is "getting the image data displayed on the computer monitor", but how I can access to that?

#### 2. What I've tried or considered

At first I tried `Electron.BrowserWindow.capturePage()` but its result didn't meet my want. It is because of two reasons: 1) My application has a transparent background and wherever area of transparency becomes black if I take a screenshot. 2) Mouse cursor is not captured together.

Meanwhile, I am aware of the existence of some APIs such as Screen Capture API and Media Capture and Streams API (in web browsers) and perhaps I can give it a try because I'm using Electron.js and Electron.js uses Chromium web browser and web browsers have implementations of those APIs.

However, it is still a problem that what those APIs handle is media streams (= video), which is not suitable for my case. Of course I think it is possible to take only one frame(?) out of a media stream somehow, but I think it is an overwork, given that what I desire for is just a single screenshot.

Meanwhile, because Electron.js also uses Node.js, I think it is also somehow possible to call Windows API (maybe via Foreign Function Interface?) or to invoke `child_process.exec()` in order to take a screenshot.

### 3. The question I would like to ask

How can I access to the monitor image data? So that I can implement "the screenshot feature which meets my requirements--see-through & mouse cursor" (if uses of third-party libraries needed, as least as possible).

What calculates a final image data which is going to be displayed on my computer monitor? It seems that it is a work of my graphics card because my monitor and graphics card are connected each other with a cable.

**4. Miscellaneous curiosities (not much related to the question)**

...Yet it is another curiosity that how, why, and where the transparent area is processed as `#000000` color.

Meanwhile it is also interesting that there are some programs which do not allow me to take a screenshot of contents on them--the area where the programs are located looks black. How could the developers of this kind of programs implement this?

---

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

After some internet searches, I found it difficult to access and get display data (specifically, **video ram** data from my graphics card). So I decided to use a workaround--It is a well-known aphorism that 'all loads lead to Rome'.

[image: cursor highlighter example]

Which means,

- See-through screenshots can be achieved by either "using native screenshot feature (the PrintScreen key)" or "using some scripts that take a picture of the entire screen".
- Screenshots with mouse cursor can be achieved by adding (= overlaying) mouse cursor image at the coordinates where my mouse cursor is located at.

However, in my case I do not actually need to save screenshots as files, so I think it is enough to just draw a custom mouse cursor image, hide the original mouse cursor image, make it follow the mouse cursor, and take a screenshot with a manual key press. (I think it is also a feasible option to take a screenshot with the PrintScreen key press, get the screenshot data from the clipboard and do some image processings like adding effects relevant to a mouse cursor.

※ I saw a code that simulates "key press" (`SendKey()`) in order to take a screenshot and I think this is a good approach because of no manual key press needed.

---

I think whom interested in this topic may find it helpful from the following links (the numerical order does not represent importance):

Keywords mentioned: **GetDC(), BitBlt(), CAPTUREBLT flag, GDI**

- [What is the best way to take screenshots of a Window with C++ in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531684/what-is-the-best-way-to-take-screenshots-of-a-window-with-c-in-windows)
- [How can I take a screenshot in a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-in-a-windows-application)

Keywords mentioned: **DirectX, buffer**

- [Fastest method of screen capturing on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069104/fastest-method-of-screen-capturing-on-windows)
- [How to save backbuffer to file in DirectX 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120108/how-to-save-backbuffer-to-file-in-directx-10/4286971#4286971)

Keywords mentioned: **mouse cursor, cursor image, hot spot**

- [Capture screen shot with mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628919/capture-screen-shot-with-mouse-cursor)
- [C# - Capturing the Mouse cursor image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918990/c-sharp-capturing-the-mouse-cursor-image)
- [Python - Take screenshot including mouse cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72328718/python-take-screenshot-including-mouse-cursor)

Keywords mentioned: **PowerShell, CopyFromScreen()**

- [How can I do a screen capture in Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969321/how-can-i-do-a-screen-capture-in-windows-powershell)
- [Capture screenshot of active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/capture-screenshot-of-active-window)

Q/A about **accessing to video memory**

- DRM [Access the whole video memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736244/access-the-whole-video-memory)
- raw video memory, video driver [Access the whole video memory through OpenGL programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555905/access-the-whole-video-memory-through-opengl-programming)
- graphics RAM [API to get the graphics or video memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866371/api-to-get-the-graphics-or-video-memory)
- direct data write to video memory
  [Direct video buffer access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828052/direct-video-buffer-access)
- [How to write data directly into video memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520687/how-to-write-data-directly-into-video-memory)
- [Is direct video card access possible? (No API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849200/is-direct-video-card-access-possible-no-api)